# Sublime3: read dataframe from file, which name given by command line argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, command-line-arguments, indentation

All the time I worked with ipython notebook, but for now I should pass to script .py. And something that seems easy in ipython turns out more difficult while writing the normal scrips (correct me if I misunderstand something). 
So for instance I need to read the dataframe (and then perform some operations with this dataframe) from file, which name I want to give as argument in command line as:

```
python myfile.py filename.csv
```

For this I write the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import sys

def read_file(filesrc):
    df = pd.read_csv(filesrc, 
                     sep= '\t', 
                     names=['id', 'date', 'name', 'age'], 
                     parse_dates=['date'], 
                     infer_datetime_format=True)
    print "Reading file..."
    df1 = (df.drop(['id'], 1)
             .sort_index(by=['date'], ascending=True)
             .reset_index()
             .drop('index', 1))
    return df1.to_csv('just_df.csv')

def main():
    filesrc = sys.argv[1]
    read_file(filesrc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I have always the Error :

```
  df1 = df.drop(['id'], 1).sort_index(by=['date'], ascending=True).reset_index().drop('index', 1)     
                                                                                            ^
    IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I pay attention to tabs and space indetation, and, working in Sublime3, I have no warning about missing or extra indents in this case, so I'm surprised to see this error, and I guess that something wrong could be with other part of script, maybe reading from `sys.argv[1]` or smth else, so your help and advices will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IndentationError can be only an indentation error! Double check it. On Sublime, try View -> Indentation -> Convert indentation to tab... and see if that line goes out of the indentation level.